# Could not convert [sku.index] to boolean

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, elasticsearch

I am facing issue in my elastic search and Magento. Please find the error message below.

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Could not convert [sku.index] to boolean"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Could not convert [sku.index] to boolean","caused_by":{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Failed to parse value [not_analyzed] as only [true] or [false] are allowed."}},"status":400}
```

From the error I can understand that elastic search is accepting a boolean value for SKU, but Magento is passing some other datatype. Please help me resolve this issue. your help is much appreciated